# HAProxy example for sending h2c traffic to backend with SSL termination

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, http2

I would appreciate some help getting my HA-Proxy instance set up to accept h2 or http/1.1 traffic and perform SSL termination using the **http** mode. I have tried the following setup:

```
frontend local_fe
    mode http
    option http-use-htx
    bind *:8080 proto h2
    default_backend local_be

backend local_be
    mode http
    option http-use-htx
    server localhost localhost:9090 proto h2
```

However, using proto h2 still sends over the packets using https ([as reported by my backend](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/incorrect-scheme-set-while-proxying-to-a-http-2-cleartext-h2c-backend/3618)). Any suggestions to what I should change in my config?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting up both your front and backend at HTTP, the TCP packets will be forwarded as-is, and no termination will be preformed.

Setup your frontend as HTTPS / SSL, and keep your backend as-is.

```
frontend www-https
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/example.com.pem proto h2
   default_backend local_be
```

This config will bind to SSL port 443, preform an SSL termination with the *example.com.pem* key / certificate, and then forward the unencrypted connection to your backend.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I should have been clearer in the question. My issue is that the backend is seeing https as the incoming scheme. The way the frontend is configured, it should not be receiving https traffic.

Comment: Well it seems that your current config has HA Proxy acting in both HTTP modes for both front, and backend. This means that no transformation will be done between incoming and forwarded requests. Your frontend should be HTTPS, and your backend as HTTP. This config will trigger the decryption of the messages.

Comment: The way your frontend is configured, is to pass data to the backend without doing anything.

Comment: Yes, that is the intent. However, HA-Proxy is sending the traffic to the backend using https scheme. Some details here: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/incorrect-scheme-set-while-proxying-to-a-http-2-cleartext-h2c-backend/3618